# Setting up SocketIO and Flask I'm getting this error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ssl_socket' referenced before assignment"

Tags: javascript, python, flask, socket.io, flask-socketio

I am setting up socketio with flask and am having some errors that are preventing it from running.

```
File "src/gevent/greenlet.py", line 705, in gevent._greenlet.Greenlet.run     
  File "/Users/hairy/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/baseserver.py", line 26, in _handle_and_close_when_done
  return handle(*args_tuple)
File "/Users/hairy/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gevent/server.py", line 193, in wrap_socket_and_handle
   ssl_socket.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ssl_socket' referenced before assignment  
2019-07-30T15:07:15Z <Greenlet "Greenlet-0" at 0x102908500: _handle_and_close_when_done(<bound method WSGIServer.wrap_socket_and_handle of, <bound method WSGIServer.do_close of <WSGIServer a, (<socket at 0x1067882d0 fileno=[Errno 9] Bad file )> failed with UnboundLocalError
```

Here is my flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, Markup
from util import getHtml, duplicate, displayArray
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return displayArray()
@socketio.on('connect')
def test_connect():
    emit('after connect',  {'data':'Lets dance'})
@socketio.on('plz reload', namespace='/test')
def test_message(message):
    emit('reload', {'data': message['data']})

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', Debug=True)
```

Here is my js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
//  var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test');
//      var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
    socket.on('connect', function() {
            socket.emit('my event', {data: 'I\'m connected!'});
        });
    socket.on('reload', function(msg) {
        $('#log').append('<p>Received: ' + msg.data + '</p>');
        location.reload();
    });
});
```

The app does not load when I go to localhost:5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by changing

```
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5000');
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect();
```

in the js. I'm not sure why this fixed it, but it did.

Comment: Are you running your server with SSL? The first option was connecting without encryption, the second connects through the same URL of the main page, so if that was https:// the connection to Socket.IO would also be https://.

Comment: No, i wasn't using ssl.